# Is there a data structure that supports O(1) subsequence deletion and insertion

Tags: data-structures

I was looking for a way to optimize strings so that you could delete contiguous segments in them faster than Θ(n) since I would be doing a lot of removal operations and my code is under a time limit.

I tried using a linked list since you just need to change the "next" variable in a node to insert or remove segments.

Although this does lead to O(1) removal insertion and deletion, I would first have to traverse the linked list in Θ(n) time to the node/index where I would want to insert/delete at. Is there a modified-version version of this so I don't have to traverse the linked list every time I want to insert/delete?

If there is no such thing, do I have to build a custom one or are these requirements impossible?

Answer (score 0):

A very common data structure for this is called a Rope: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)

The C++ `std::deque` is another from which you may draw inspiration, though it is probably not directly suitable in its most common implementations (the API probably doesn't give you enough control, and the chunk sizes are not configurable).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think insertion and deletion of sub-segments can be done in `O(1)` . You can however do both of this using a [**treap**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Treap) in `O(logN)` . You will need to modify a bit and use an implicit treap .

I once solved a similar problem using this . You can find my implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/zarif98sjs/db8010ecd09bfacc10e31fd6caff00a2) . Change it according to your need if you want to use .